# Command "ping" is not found error discord.py

Tags: python, api, discord.py

Whenever I run my discord python code, and test it in the discord chat, it says the ping command is not found even though I defined it in the code and the .run(token) command is at the bottom.

The error message I get is: "Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found"

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
token = "[private token]"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def whenReady():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("What it do babyy")

client.run(token)
```

The bot should've replied with the phrase "what it do babyy" when I type in the !ping command but instead I get the error.

I also did replace the private token in code above with filler for obvious reasons.

Any helps would be appreciated, I am new to the discord API and I'm learning off the documentation and some forums here and there.

Comment: What's the error you are getting from the console?

Comment: Is the event `whenReady` printing at all?

Comment: whenReady did now print when I was checking now but I tried passing the parameter "pass_context=True" and that seemed to fix the ping function, now I don't get any errors from the console but the whenReady event doesn't print.

Comment: Try to use `on_ready` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the parameter `pass_context = True`

```
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
TOKEN = "token"

@client.event
async def whenReady():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("What it do babyy")

client.run(token)
```